# How to resolve (OAuthException) (#100) CTA is only supported for external shares?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

Please, we are creating a facebook ad and it results in this problem.
(OAuthException) (#100) CTA is only supported for external shares?

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the error message is accurate it means you're trying to create Page Post with the 'call_to_action' set, but the link inside the page post is to a facebook.com URL - that's not supported and is what the error message refers to - you should link to somewhere off-Facebook if you want to use a custom call to action in the post